# Return Result AFTER foreach in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```html
let arrData = [];
arrGotData.forEach(function(objGotData) {
            let arrDataLength = arrData.length;
            //do something
            arrData[arrDataLength] = objGotData;
}
return arrData;
```

How could I return my arrData AFTER the forEach got executed and not before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the bracket `)` after `}`

Check out the working code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fejm5v)

Adding the same code here for reference

```
fun() {
    let arrData = [];
    this.arrGotData.forEach((objGotData) => {   
    let arrDataLength = arrData.length;
    //do something
    arrData[arrDataLength] = objGotData;
   });   
    return arrData; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I just typed it in here and didn´t pasted it so I mistyped. Thats not my problem. My problem is, that arrData is returned BEFORE my forEach loop is executed

Comment: Check the link that I have provided, it is returning the array after completion of foreach loop.